# Contact Key on Marketing Cloud Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object, journeybuilder

In our scenario, we need to trigger a Marketing Cloud journey on updation of a Sales Cloud custom object.

Is it possible that the ID of the custom object becomes the contact key on the Journey.

When we are running the Journey, the contact key is the ID of the Person Account associated with the custom object and not the ID of the custom object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set whatever field you fancy as the Id/key in the Journey entry data extension. As you map the 'field relates to subscribers on subscriber key'

What you set does have consequences though to your contact model. If you interchange the key between data extensions then you will end up with duplicates on the all subscribed list.

If you want to join tracking to Salesforce Contact object then you need to use the 18 digit contact id. Else the clouds won't know who you are referring to